# find peaks and valleys for each column of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe df, I would like to find peaks and valleys for each column and then replace the points where peaks and valleys are present with the value 1.
Here I made an example by applying it to only one column.

Is it possible to do this for all the columns in the dataframe?

```
df <- data.frame(a = sample(1:10,10),
             b = sample(1:10,10),
             c = sample(1:10,10),
             d = sample(1:10,10),
             e = sample(1:10,10))



vallys<- findValleys(df$b, thresh =0)
peaks <- findPeaks(df$b, thresh = 0)
df$b  <- rep(0, nrow(df))
df$b  <- replace(df$b, peaks, values=1)
df$b  <- replace(df$b, vallys, values=1)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to put your code into a function.

```r
library(quantmod)

replace_peaks_valleys <- function(x) {

    valleys <- findValleys(x, thresh = 0)
    peaks <- findPeaks(x, thresh = 0)

    new_col <- rep(0, length(x))
    new_col <- replace(new_col, peaks, values = 1)
    new_col <- replace(new_col, valleys, values = 1)
    return(new_col)
}
```

Then you can choose whether to do it in base R, `dplyr` or `data.table`.

#### base R

As you want to assign back to your original data frame, in base R you can do (note the square brackets or it will return a list):

```r
df[]  <- lapply(df, replace_peaks_valleys)
head(df)
#   a b c d e
# 1 0 0 0 0 0
# 2 0 0 0 0 0
# 3 1 1 1 1 1
# 4 1 0 1 1 0
# 5 1 1 0 1 0
# 6 0 1 1 1 1
```

#### dplyr

Alternatively, with `dplyr` you can just do:

```r
library(dplyr)
df  |>
    mutate(
        across(
            a:e, replace_peaks_valleys
        )
    )
#    a b c d e
# 1  0 0 0 0 0
# 2  0 0 0 0 0
# 3  1 1 1 1 1
# 4  1 0 1 1 0
# <etc>
```

#### data.table

You can also do this with `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
dt  <- setDT(df)

dt[, lapply(.SD, replace_peaks_valleys)]
#     a b c d e
#  1: 0 0 0 0 0
#  2: 0 0 0 0 0
#  3: 1 0 1 1 1
# 4: 1 1 0 0 0
# <etc>
```

N.B. I used `set.seed(1)` before I ran your code - if you do this as well you should exactly the same output.

#### Function definition

I just copied and pasted your code and made it into a function. You could change it so you assign 0 or 1 to the existing vector, rather than creating a new vector every time:

```r
replace_peaks_valleys2 <- function(x) {
    valleys <- findValleys(x, thresh = 0)
    peaks <- findPeaks(x, thresh = 0)

    x[]  <- 0
    x[c(peaks,valleys)]  <- 1

    return(x)
}
```